# source control structure for a kohana based project

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, kohana-3

i currently have several projects using kohana as a framework, and what i have at the moment
is a directory structure like this

```
project
- application
- system
- modules
```

the "project" dir is under mercurial source control, and i basically copy and paste modules that i use. and commit them to each project.

however i am now finding i fix a bug in a module and there is no easy way to propogate that fix to all the other projects using that module.

what i am wanting to do is link the modules somehow so i can easily get updates when i need them. (i have been looking at subrepos for doing this)

now i read up this on the mercurial site
"Use a thin shell repository to manage your subrepositories"

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Subrepository

so i came up with this concept

```
applications
- application1 (hg repo)
- application2 (hg repo)

mymodules
- mymodule1 (hg repo)
- mymodule2 (hg repo)

project  (hg repo)
- application (sub repo pointing to applications/application1)
- modules (several git repos on github, custom modules which are in mymodules/module1 repos)
- system (git repo on github)

website
- project (links to project repo, including application, modules and system)
- assets (images, css, etc)
```

now i am thinking that is a lot of structure and i am going a bit over the top for what is essentially a simple problem.

Also I am not sure how i should i be doing work.

1. in my the website repos and pushing back to project, which would get pushed back to the application, and modules etc
2. or should i be working on the application repos and pushing up to the website level?

So is this the best way to structure things?

also is it necessary to have a local clone of all the github modules i use, to speed things up?

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subrepos solution is a good one, as it allows to separate:

- the **development structure** (composed of all your repos)
- the **deployment structure** (i.e. the structure you need for your program to compile and run, or to your website to be displayed properly)

How to make it works means how you organize your **release management** process.
You should make modifications from your repos, and then propagate them to the deployment structures (through updates within projects, and then update of project within website).